# Translation of the OG's User Roles

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups, i18n-l10n

I have a view which contains the relationship **"OG membership: OG Roles from membership"**, and the only thing I need is to translate the retrieved values from this relationship.

What is your recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue which is worked on here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1473262